# Azure - multiple sites on 1 role physical directory post build event

Tags: azure

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/641913/visual-studio-azure-tools-sdk-1-3-not-packaging-multiple-sites-correctly

I can add a post build event which will package up my 2nd website.

**Problem:** Which physicalDirectory should I use in ServiceDefinition.csdef?

```
  <Sites>
  <Site name="Web">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="HttpIn" endpointName="HttpIn" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
  <Site name="WebMVCAdmin" physicalDirectory="f:\publishMVCAdmin">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="HttpIn" endpointName="HttpIn" hostHeader="pvadmin8.xxx.co.nz" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
```

am using SDK1.3